# php calling phython script with long executing time does not show output

Tags: php, python, ssh, timeout, phpseclib

I have written a php program "myphp.php" which will collect data from a python script "test.py" running in "mysnmpserver".
When I run a simple "hello world" python script, it works. But the php echo doesn't show anything when I use the python script with the SNMP library(which takes around 2 min to execute-  'basically collects all the network information').

My myphp.php file is as bellow:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$server = "mysnmpserver";
$username = "user";
$command = "./test.py";
$pass = "pass";

$ssh = new Net_SSH2($server);
if(!$ssh->login($username, $pass)){
    exit('login failed!');
}

echo $ssh->exec($command);
```

It would be a great help if any one suggest me what should be the appropriate code

Comment: Is this PHP script run via a HTTP request from a browser? if yes, the connection probably timeouts before the Python script ends

Comment: yes PHP script run  via HTTP request from browser, is there any solution for this?

Comment: hum... It is not really related to connection timeout as I stated before, but you could try to see the [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function or the php.ini [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) parameter. If it does not fix the problem, you could try to tweak the http timeout of your browser.

Comment: I have tried but still the same situation

Comment: I'd enable logging by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and then doing `$ssh->getLog()` at the bottom and then post the output into pastebin.com. Then add that link to your question. That'll let people look at the SSH logs to gain insight into what's going on. Like one possibility: maybe a PTY is needed to get the output. If that's the case you could do `$ssh->enablePTY()` but the logs will give us more insight, regardless.